# I have had 2 BSOD since upgrading to Win10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have had 2 BSOD, one called "Video_scheduler_internal_error". & the other called "PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA" . Can someone tell me what this means?? This PC is brand new. About a week old. i just upgraded to Windows 10 and all of a sudden I get 2 blue screens of death

Comment: dumb question, but I f i remove the graphic card , can I still see the screen?

Comment: share the dmp fiels from C:\Windows\minidump.

Comment: theres nothing there, its empty

Comment: have you disabled the pagefile? Windows needs it to create dumps.

Comment: Take the PC back and ask for help, it's within warranty

Answer (score 2):

Intel's support for their older graphics chipsets at Windows 10 launch has been less than optimal.  Many people are complaining that their various Intel graphics cards are having issues.

I use two laptops for media centers, both with older Intel chipsets.  Both machines are having issues with the driver that was released.  One machine works relatively well, but I am unable to modify the overscan settings.  The other laptop is more problematic.  It cannot display to the laptop screen, but will display out the DisplayPort.  It is also unable to adjust the overscan settings.  In addition to that, the driver fails when going to sleep mode.

There isnt much you can do, but wait and hope they write proper drivers.

Comment: so what can we do?

Comment: "There isnt much you can do, but wait and hope they write proper drivers."

Answer (score 1):

By any chance do you have a Nividia graphics card? There have been [issues](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/07/28/windows_10_update_nvidia_driver_conflict/) with drivers since the launch so this could be why. To answer your previous question if you have a dedicated card you're using you could try switching to your on board graphics card until driver issues are resolved.

Comment: No, im using the intel hd 4600 card that it came with.

Comment: Looks like you're not alone with these [issues](https://communities.intel.com/thread/75672)

Apparently Windows 10 is not "fully compatible" with your graphics card, but the article claims there will be support upon release.

Comment: @Coeus - Which already happened?

Comment: This should be acomment, not an "answer"